# Using python subprocess, how to get the output from executing a decryption command?

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess

Is there a way to get the output value from a subprocess that decrypts a file? Getting a variable with the output and creating the decrypted file in the directory are both good solutions - I just need to get the decrypted value.

Code:

`decryption_result = subprocess.run(['openssl', 'decrypt', '-inkey', private_key_file,'-in', message_file, '-out', name])`

Answer (score 1):

Add the argument `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and you could use

```
decryption_result.stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

EDIT:
From the official documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

```
decryption_result = subprocess.run(['openssl', 'decrypt', '-inkey', private_key_file,'-in', message_file, '-out', name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
decryption_result.stdout.decode("utf-8")
```